# SqlDbType and own created SQL Server type

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, types, ado.net

Which type do I have to choose if I want to send a `DataTable` to SQL Server 2008? Because I created my own type for a table to provide the transfer of the datatable.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.LipperFilesTestingInsertFileRowKey", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DataTable", SqlDbType.???, 512));
```

**SQL**

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[keytable] AS TABLE (key varchar(512))
```

Stored procedure "short form":

```
create procedure insertkeys
    @indicater, @keys keytable readonly
as
begin
    insert into dbo.tableA 
        select * 
        from @keys
end
```

Comment: This is covered in the documentation for [Table-Valued Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: so its structured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type you should use is; 
`SqlDbType.Structured`